# Accessing user fields in controller helper does not work

Tags: haskell, ihp

#### Context

In a controller, I have a function that is called via `beforeAction` to check if a certain field on `user` is null or not. If it is null, the user should be redirected to a certain action in another controller.

Since I want to call this function from almost every controller in my application, putting it in `Application.Helper.Controller` seems the right choice, but I cannot figure out the type signature.

The function is as follows, and in a normal controller this works:

```
ensureIsSubscribed :: _ => IO ()
ensureIsSubscribed = do
    case currentUserOrNothing of
        Just loggedInUser -> do
            case (get #subscriptionId loggedInUser) of
                Nothing -> redirectToPath "/NewCheckoutSession"
                _ -> redirectToPath "/Welcome"
        Nothing -> pure ()
```

but when putting the above in `Application.Helper.Controller` I get this error:

```
• Could not deduce (HasField
                      "subscriptionId" CurrentUserRecord (Maybe a0))
    arising from a use of ‘get’
  from the context: ?context::ControllerContext
    bound by the inferred type of
               ensureIsSubscribed :: (?context::ControllerContext) => IO ()
    at Application/Helper/Controller.hs:(8,1)-(14,26)
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
• In the expression: (get #subscriptionId loggedInUser)
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    case (get #subscriptionId loggedInUser) of
      Nothing -> redirectToPath "/NewCheckoutSession"
      _ -> redirectToPath "/Welcome"
  In the expression:
    do case (get #subscriptionId loggedInUser) of
         Nothing -> redirectToPath "/NewCheckoutSession"
         _ -> redirectToPath "/Welcome"
   |
11 |             case (get #subscriptionId loggedInUser) of
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Question

Why does the above not work and what is the correct type signature (if that is the problem)?

Comment: Try to fix ambiguous of type variable `a0`.  Change `_ -> redirectToPath "/Welcome"` to `Just (_ :: ProperType) -> redirectToPath "/Welcome"` where `ProperType` is type of subscription ID (I don't known it).

Comment: Basically, It's look like `CurrentUserRecord` hasn't field  `subscriptionId`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! The fix lay in another direction (see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CurrentUserRecord` is defined in `Web/Types.hs` as `type instance CurrentUserRecord = User`. If the `Web.Types` module is not imported, the type `CurrentUserRecord` cannot be replaced with it's definition `User`.

The fix is therefore to add an `import Web.Types` to your `Application.Helper.Controller` module :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that before since I guessed that might be the problem but it does not solve the error which is now: `Could not deduce (HasField "subscriptionId" Generated.Types.User (Maybe a0)) arising from a use of ‘get’ from the context: ?context::ControllerContext`

Comment: Can you add an `import Generated.Types`? Maybe the User type is not in scope.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the import Generated.Types was the final key to the solution!